# Xamarin looking for resources at the wrong place

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Environment: Visual Studio 2015, Xamarin 4.7.9.45, Xamarin Android 7.4.5.1

My development environment used to work fine until yesterday and now I am not able to debug properly. While loading string resources, the following code from `AppResources.designer.cs` throws a "file-not-found" exception:

```
 public static string Button_Username {
   get {
      return ResourceManager.GetString("Button_Username", resourceCulture);
   }
 }
```

The resource culture is "en-US." The string resource `Button_Username` is indeed defined. Otherwise, the above lines of code wouldn't even be there in the auto-generated `AppResources.designer.cs` file.

Upon inspecting the exception in the debugger, it appears Xamarin is trying to load the following file:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp.mycomp.com/
    files/.__override__/en-US/MyProject.resources.dll
```

We generate `MyProject.resources.dll` for many other languages but not en-US as it is the default language. Why is Xamarin trying to load this dll? Shouldn't it be looking into resources.arsc file? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

> We generate MyProject.resources.dll for many other languages but not en-US as it is the default language. Why is Xamarin trying to load this dll? Shouldn't it be looking into resources.arsc file?

`resources.arsc` works for Android Native localization. But you are currently developing a Xamarin.Forms App and using its localization, where the related `.resw` files will be complied into `MyProject.resources.dll` and as your project sets `en-US` as the default culture.

If you have created `AppResources.en-US.resw` file and current culture is `en-US`. Your app will try to look for this file, which is contained in `.../en-US/MyProject.resources.dll`.

If you didn't created `AppResources.en-US.resw` your app will search the string in `AppResources.resw` file.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After running a repair on VS2015, the problem seems to have disappeared. However, although ours is a Xamarin Forms app, we do not have any en-US/Myproject.resources.dll and still everything is working. Makes me think that resources.arsc is being used. Regards.